# Why will custom dimensions not work in case statements. Data studio, Google analytics

Tags: google-analytics, looker-studio, case-statement

I am having an issue in Google data studio. I am creating a case statements that looks for keywords in a few different dimensions and categorises them accordingly. This all works fine until I add a custom dimensions. The see statement is valid as far as Google is concerned but it returns nothing.

```
CASE 
WHEN CONTAINS_TEXT(PAGE, "Heart") THEN "Cardiology"
WHEN PAGE = "Diabetes.website.com" THEN "Diabetes"
End
```

The above works fine

```
CASE 
    WHEN CONTAINS_TEXT(PAGE, "Heart") THEN "Cardiology"
    WHEN PAGE = "Diabetes.website.com" THEN "Diabetes"
WHEN WEB_SUBJECT = "Hypertension" THEN "Cardiology"
END
```

The above is valid but is blank when used. Web_subject is a custom dimensions defined in Google analytics.

Any help greatly appreciate. This one has me stumped.

UPDATE:
So changing the format of the custom dimension expression to be REGEX worked in returning results for that particular condition but it now does not show results for any others. I have a feeling it may because of the data sitting behind it all.

A little more context, the data source in this case is a roll up google analytics account, So it contains analytics from 10+ domains. What I am attempting to do is group together page views and users from different domains into subjects using various different dimensions. For example if a USER selects the filter 'Diabetes' I want to return all pageviews for:
Domain A where page title contains x
Domain B where customDimesnion 1 = Y
etc

This is my current mess of a CASE statement:

```
    case
when contains_text(Page, 'biosimilars-confidence') OR REGEXP_MATCH(WEBSITE subject,  '.*(?i)(Oncologie).*') OR CONTAINS_TEXT(Page, 'oncology') OR contains_text(Page, 'rrmm-challenges') OR  contains_text(Page, 'oncologyhighlights2020') OR CONTAINS_TEXT(Page, 'ASCO') OR CONTAINS_TEXT(Page Title, 'cancer') OR contains_text(Page Title, 'Oncology') OR  contains_text(Page Title, 'ASCO') THEN "Oncology"
when CONTAINS_TEXT(Page, 'DOMAINB') OR contains_text(Page, 'eprint') THEN "Eprint"
when CONTAINS_TEXT(Page, 'diabetes') OR REGEXP_MATCH(WEBSITE subject,  '.*(?i)(Diabetes).*') OR contains_text(Page, 'hypoglycemia') OR contains_text(Page, 'glp1ras') OR contains_text(Page Title, 'Diabetes') OR contains_text(Page Title, 'hyperglycemia') OR contains_text(Page Title, 'diabetes') OR contains_text(Page Title, 'ADA') OR contains_text(Page Title, 'GLP-1') then "Diabetes/Endocrinology"
when CONTAINS_TEXT(Page, 'cardiology') OR REGEXP_MATCH(WEBSITE subject,  '.*(?i)(Cardiologie).*') OR contains_text(Page Title, 'Cardiology') OR contains_text(Page Title, 'Heart failure') then'Cardiology'
when contains_text(Page, 'gastro') OR REGEXP_MATCH(WEBSITE subject,  '.*(?i)(Gastro-enterologie).*') OR contains_text(Page Title, 'Gastroenterology') then "Gastroenterology"
when contains_text(Page, 'rheumatology') OR REGEXP_MATCH(WEBSITE subject,  '.*(?i)(Reumatologie).*') OR contains_text(Page Title, 'Rheumatology') OR contains_text(Page Title, 'adalimumab') OR CONTAINS_TEXT(Page Title, 'arthritis') OR CONTAINS_TEXT(Page Title, 'EULAR') OR contains_text(Page Title, "joint")  then "Rheumatology"
when CONTAINS_TEXT(Page, 'migraine') OR REGEXP_MATCH(WEBSITE subject,  '.*(?i)(Neurologie).*') OR contains_text(Page Title, 'Neurology') OR contains_text(Page Title, "Ataxia") OR contains_text(Page Title, "EAN 2020") then "Neurology"
when Page = 'DOMAINA.com' OR contains_text(Page, 'training') OR Page = 'ime.DOMAINA.com' then "Corporate site traffic"
when contains_text(Page Title, 'Gynaecology ') then "Gynaecology "
when CONTAINS_TEXT(Page Title, 'Dermatology') OR REGEXP_MATCH(WEBSITE subject,  '.*(?i)(Dermatologie).*') OR contains_text(Page Title, 'eczema') OR contains_text(Page Title, 'Laser hair removal') then "Dermatology"
when CONTAINS_TEXT(Page Title, 'COVID-19') OR REGEXP_MATCH(WEBSITE subject,  '.*(?i)(Coronavirus (COVID-19)).*') then "COVID-19"
WHEN CONTAINS_TEXT(Page Title, 'General practice') then "General practice"
when contains_text(Page Title, 'Haematology') OR REGEXP_MATCH(WEBSITE subject,  '.*(?i)(Hematologie).*') OR contains_text(Page Title, 'EHA25') then "Haematology"
when contains_text(Page Title, 'Mental health') OR CONTAINS_TEXT(Page Title, 'Psychology') then 'Mental health'
when contains_text(Page Title, 'penile length') OR REGEXP_MATCH(WEBSITE subject,  '.*(?i)(Urologie).*') then "Urology"
when contains_text(Page Title, 'ERS 2019') OR REGEXP_MATCH(WEBSITE subject,  '.*(?i)(Longziekten).*') THEN "Lung diseases"
when contains_text(Page, 'noonan')Then "Genetics"
when REGEXP_MATCH(WEBSITE subject,  '.*(?i)(Farmacie).*') then 'Pharmacy'
when REGEXP_MATCH(WEBSITE subject,  '.*(?i)(Heelkunde).*') then 'Surgery'
when REGEXP_MATCH(WEBSITE subject,  '.*(?i)(Huisartsgeneeskunde).*') then 'Family medicine'
when REGEXP_MATCH(WEBSITE subject,  '.*(?i)(Infectieziekten).*') then 'Infectious Diseases'
when REGEXP_MATCH(WEBSITE subject,  '.*(?i)(Overig).*') then 'Other/Uncategorized'
when REGEXP_MATCH(WEBSITE subject,  '.*(?i)(Voeding).*') then 'Nutrition'
else 'Other/Uncategorized'
end
```

I have anonymised some bits so if it looks strange that is why.
It may well be I am going about this in completely the wrong way. One other thing to note, the domain names are stored in the PAGE dimension.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Update (Expanded CASE)

### 0) Original Expanded CASE

It may be due to:

```
contains_text(Page Title, 'ADA')
```

Adding a **Word Boundary** around `ADA` may do the trick, ensuring that words that simply contain `ADA` are not captured into the respective `WHEN` clause

```
REGEXP_MATCH(Page Title, ".*(?i)(\\bADA\\b).*")
```

An alternative is to follow the two step process below:

### 1) Field_CONCAT

Create the following Data Source-level [Calculated Field](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/6299685) to [`CONCAT`](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7583443) the fields into one single consolidated field:

```sql
CONCAT(Page, ", ", WEBSITE subject, ", ", Page Title)
```

### 2) New_CASE

Create the [`CASE`](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7020724) statement below:

- ***Field***: Where `Field_CONCAT` represents the field created above;
- ***| OR |***: The `|` Pipe operators `|` serve as the RegEx version of `OR`
- ***Escape Sequence***: `\\` is used to escape special RegEx characters such as `(`, `|`, `.`, etc;
- ***Word Boundaries***: Added a word boundary on either side of `ADA` (as well as `ASCO`) to ensure that text that simply contain `ada` are not part of the `Diabetes/Endocrinology` WHEN clause:

```sql
CASE
  WHEN REGEXP_MATCH(Field_CONCAT, ".*(?i)(biosimilars-confidence|Oncologie|oncology|rrmm-challenges|oncologyhighlights2020|\\bASCO\\b|cancer).*") THEN "Oncology"
  WHEN REGEXP_MATCH(Field_CONCAT, ".*(?i)(DOMAINB|eprint).*") THEN "Eprint"
  WHEN REGEXP_MATCH(Field_CONCAT, ".*(?i)(diabetes|hypoglycemia|glp1ras|hyperglycemia|\\bADA\\b|GLP-1).*") THEN "Diabetes/Endocrinology"
  WHEN REGEXP_MATCH(Field_CONCAT, ".*(?i)(cardiology|Cardiologie|Heart failure).*") THEN 'Cardiology'
  WHEN REGEXP_MATCH(Field_CONCAT, ".*(?i)(gastro|Gastro-enterologie|Gastroenterology).*") THEN "Gastroenterology"
  WHEN REGEXP_MATCH(Field_CONCAT, ".*(?i)(rheumatology|Reumatologie|adalimumab|arthritis|EULAR|joint).*") THEN "Rheumatology"
  WHEN REGEXP_MATCH(Field_CONCAT, ".*(?i)(migraine|Neurologie|Neurology|Ataxia|EAN 2020).*") THEN "Neurology"
  WHEN REGEXP_MATCH(Field_CONCAT, ".*(?i)(DOMAINA\\.com|training|ime\\.DOMAINA\\.com).*") THEN "Corporate site traffic"
  WHEN REGEXP_MATCH(Field_CONCAT, ".*(?i)(Gynaecology).*") THEN "Gynaecology "
  WHEN REGEXP_MATCH(Field_CONCAT, ".*(?i)(Dermatology|Dermatologie|eczema|Laser hair removal).*") THEN "Dermatology"
  WHEN REGEXP_MATCH(Field_CONCAT, ".*(?i)(COVID-19|Coronavirus \\(COVID-19\\)).*") THEN "COVID-19"
  WHEN REGEXP_MATCH(Field_CONCAT, ".*(?i)(General practice).*") THEN "General practice"
  WHEN REGEXP_MATCH(Field_CONCAT, ".*(?i)(Haematology|Hematologie|EHA25).*") THEN "Haematology"
  WHEN REGEXP_MATCH(Field_CONCAT, ".*(?i)(Mental health|Psychology).*") THEN 'Mental health'
  WHEN REGEXP_MATCH(Field_CONCAT, ".*(?i)(penile length|Urologie).*") THEN "Urology"
  WHEN REGEXP_MATCH(Field_CONCAT, ".*(?i)(ERS 2019|Longziekten).*") THEN "Lung diseases"
  WHEN REGEXP_MATCH(Field_CONCAT, ".*(?i)(noonan).*") THEN "Genetics"
  WHEN REGEXP_MATCH(Field_CONCAT, ".*(?i)(Farmacie).*") THEN 'Pharmacy'
  WHEN REGEXP_MATCH(Field_CONCAT, ".*(?i)(Heelkunde).*") THEN 'Surgery'
  WHEN REGEXP_MATCH(Field_CONCAT, ".*(?i)(Huisartsgeneeskunde).*") THEN 'Family medicine'
  WHEN REGEXP_MATCH(Field_CONCAT, ".*(?i)(Infectieziekten).*") THEN 'Infectious Diseases'
  WHEN REGEXP_MATCH(Field_CONCAT, ".*(?i)(Overig).*") THEN 'Other/Uncategorized'
  WHEN REGEXP_MATCH(Field_CONCAT, ".*(?i)(Voeding).*") THEN 'Nutrition'
  ELSE 'Other/Uncategorized'
END
```

Added a [New Page to the Google Data Studio Report](https://datastudio.google.com/reporting/782fa895-af17-4384-a9fe-2f50fdb4bf23/page/w33eB) and a GIF to demonstrate:

[image]

## Original POST

### 0) `ELSE NULL`

Note that the [`CASE`](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7020724) statements in the question and this suggestion have not explicitly stated the `ELSE` clause, thus by default, `ELSE` values are treated as **NULL**.

### 1) Tweaked CASE

Tried out the [`CASE`](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7020724) statement and it works as expected! One tweak to the initial CASE statement is the inclusion of a **Logical Operator**, `OR`:

```sql
CASE
  WHEN CONTAINS_TEXT(PAGE, "Heart") OR WEB_SUBJECT = "Hypertension" THEN "Cardiology"
  WHEN PAGE = "Diabetes.website.com" THEN "Diabetes"
END
```

### 2) Alternative CASE

In addition, you could also have a look to see whether the [`CASE`](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7020724) statement below resolves the issue; it uses the [`REGEXP_MATCH`](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7064476) function and ensures that fields **Contain** `.*` the respective values as well as adding a **Case Insensitive Flag** `(?i)` thus matching `Hypertension`, `hypertension`, `HYPerTENsion`, etc:

```sql
CASE
  WHEN REGEXP_MATCH(PAGE, ".*(?i)(Heart).*") OR REGEXP_MATCH(WEB_SUBJECT, ".*(?i)(Hypertension).*") THEN "Cardiology"
  WHEN REGEXP_MATCH(PAGE, ".*(?i)(Diabetes\\.website\\.com).*") THEN "Diabetes"
END
```

### 3) Next Steps and a GIF

If the above doesn't resolve the issue, could you elaborate with a screenshot(s) and provide some sample data (removing or replacing any sensitive information); feel free to add data to [This Editable Google Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1hBIkeY0uw6JkHP3u4-s7D7FDT8-jijYN9DYDk2y5BzM/edit?usp=sharing) (also used in the Report and GIF below).

[Google Data Studio Report](https://datastudio.google.com/reporting/782fa895-af17-4384-a9fe-2f50fdb4bf23) and a GIF to elaborate on the above:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

So first of all @Nimantha thank you for getting me much further down the road on solving this and giving me a huge lesson in case statements that is going to help me massively going forward.

The problem as it turns out was that I have the 'Universal' analytics tag sitting on multiple sites implemented by different tag manager containers. I was defining custom dimensions in the tag containers to pass datalayer information through to google analytics. The problem is that i was passing no value through to the custom dimension to on any of the other domains. This caused the CASE statement to fall over as when a custom dimension value only existed on one domain, it only returned pages from that domain.

To fix this I went to all GA tags across all containers and matched up the custom dimensions, passing in (not set) if I have no actual value to give it. Now in using the CASE statement above by Nimantha I can see all of the pages starting to appear. Just unfortunate they are populating from now forward but at least it works!